# Question on triangle with heights

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, triangles

Prove that there exists no triangle with heights 4,7, and 10 units. I am completely puzzled.

Comment: If you draw two sides of a triangle, and draw two heights, then you have completely specified the triangle. So the third height is a function of the first two. So, you cannot just choose any three numbers and have a triangle with the corresponding heights.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The area of the triangle is half the product of a side of the triangle and the height of the triangle on that side. So calling the area of the triangle $A$, the sides would have to be

$$\frac{2\cdot A}{10}, \; \frac{2\cdot A}{7},\; \frac{2\cdot A}{4}.$$

But

$$\frac{1}{4} > \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{10},$$

so these "sides" could not make a triangle, since the longest is longer than the sum of the two shorter.

Comment: Would not the side be 2A/h ?

Comment: Good point. Doesn't change the result, though.

Comment: Thanks, it is now so clear. I did not realize that it was going to be so simple. I had right from the beginning dived into trigonometry and the properties of heights. Thanks, for this simple and plain answer.

Comment: @Sawarnik As an aside, you should show that if you are given 3 positive values whose reciprocals satisfy the triangle inequality, then there exists a triangle with those 3 values as height lengths. This gives you a complete characterization.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Well let the sides of the triangle be $a, b, c$ - ordered so that twice the area of the triangle is $4a=7b=10c$ (base times height). Can you use this information to express all the sides of the triangle as multiples of $a$?